# unable to reproduce curl postrequest with c# and httpClient

Tags: c#, pdf, curl, httpclient, .net-6.0

so I have [this](https://flood-map-for-planning.service.gov.uk/flood-zone-results?easting=429240&northing=431613&location=LS118TR&fullName=%20&recipientemail=%20) website

After inspecting the network traffic for the download button I got the below curl post request

```
curl "https://flood-map-for-planning.service.gov.uk/pdf" -X POST -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:104.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/104.0" -H "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8" -H "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5" -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -H "Origin: https://flood-map-for-planning.service.gov.uk" -H "Connection: keep-alive" -H "Referer: https://flood-map-for-planning.service.gov.uk/flood-zone-results?easting=429240&northing=431613&location=LS118TR" -H "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1" -H "Sec-Fetch-Dest: document" -H "Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate" -H "Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin" -H "Sec-Fetch-User: ?1" -H "TE: trailers" --data-raw "id=1660136366038&polygon=&center="%"5B429240"%"2C431613"%"5D&reference=&scale=2500"
```

I went over to [this](https://curl.olsh.me/) website in order to convert the curl to c#

This is what I got

```
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("POST"), "https://flood-map-for-planning.service.gov.uk/pdf"))
    {
        request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:104.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/104.0");
        request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8");
        request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
        request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br");
        request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Origin", "https://flood-map-for-planning.service.gov.uk");
        request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Connection", "keep-alive");
        request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Referer", "https://flood-map-for-planning.service.gov.uk/flood-zone-results?easting=429240&northing=431613&location=LS118TR");
        request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", "1");
        request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Sec-Fetch-Dest", "document");
        request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Sec-Fetch-Mode", "navigate");
        request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Sec-Fetch-Site", "same-origin");
        request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Sec-Fetch-User", "?1");
        request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("TE", "trailers"); 

        request.Content = new StringContent("id=1660136366038&polygon=&center=");
        request.Content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 

        var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
    }
}
```

I changed it to:

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
var request =
       new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("POST"), "https://flood-map-for-planning.service.gov.uk/pdf");
request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:104.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/104.0");
request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Accept", "application/pdf"); 
request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br");
request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Origin", "https://flood-map-for-planning.service.gov.uk");
request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Connection", "keep-alive");
request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Referer", "https://flood-map-for-planning.service.gov.uk/flood-zone-results?easting=429240&northing=431613&location=LS118TR");
request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", "1");
request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Sec-Fetch-Dest", "document");
request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Sec-Fetch-Mode", "navigate");
request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Sec-Fetch-Site", "same-origin");
request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Sec-Fetch-User", "?1");
request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("TE", "trailers");

request.Content = new StringContent("center=&scale=2500");

var response =  httpClient.Send(request);
response.Content.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=\"Testpdf.pdf\"");
response.Content.Headers.Add("Content-Name", "Testpdf.PDF");
response.Content.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/pdf;charset=UTF-8");

if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{

    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("somepdf.pdf", FileMode.CreateNew))
    {
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fs))
        {
            var contentStream =  response.Content.ReadAsStream(); // get the actual content stream
            writer.Write(contentStream);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the issue.

My goal is to download the pdf locally.

I usually get a file which is 1KB or 6KB.

The curl command with an output parameter works without an issue. I'm just not sure what the above c# http post request is missing.

As you can see I've added the filestream and streamwriter usages.

I've also tried to play with the response in order to nagivate it to an application/pdf response.

Any ideas why I am doing wrong?

***=======================================================***

***EDIT***

Thanks to @thehennyy,

here is the working solution:

```
 var unixTimestamp = (long)DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(DateTime.UnixEpoch).TotalSeconds;

HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler()
{
    AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate
};

using (var httpClient = new HttpClient(handler))
{
    using (var request =
           new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("POST"), "https://flood-map-for-planning.service.gov.uk/pdf"))
    {
        request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Referer",
            "https://flood-map-for-planning.service.gov.uk/flood-zone-results?easting=429240&northing=431613&location=LS118TR");

        request.Content =
            new StringContent($"id={unixTimestamp}&polygon=&center=[429240,431613]&reference=&scale=2500");
        request.Content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("somepdf.pdf", FileMode.Create))
            {
                var contentStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
                await contentStream.CopyToAsync(fs);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? What is the response status code? Does your code try to write the file and is there a problem with the file content?

Comment: The response is 200. I don't think I get the correct response for a pdf. I am able to write the file successfully, but it's either 1KB or 6 KB and the file is supposed to be around 1.4MB. The curl command saves the full pdf file successfully.

Comment: Try to add a `writer.Flush();` after `writer.Write(...);`. Maybe the file buffer is not written to disk.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however it's the same result. a 1KB file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things to consider here:

It seems like the curl to httpclient converter had a problem converting the post content. The following works for me:

```
request.Content = new StringContent("id=1&polygon=&center=[429240,431613]&reference=&scale=2500");
request.Content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

The parameter `id` has to be provided, otherwise the request will fail. The website uses the current unix timestamp as value for the id parameter.

---

Adding headers to the response `response.Content.Headers.Add([...])` is not meaningful, just delete these lines.

---

Writing the content to disk can be done simpler:

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("somepdf.pdf", FileMode.Create))
{
    var contentStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
    await contentStream.CopyToAsync(fs);
}
```

---

While testing i got the same "wrong" files, these are usual just html responses, sometimes containing an error message. View them as html. Maybe they seem like gibberish, then you have to turn on automatic decompression:

```
HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler()
{
    AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate
};

var httpClient = new HttpClient(handler);
```

The automatic decompression values should match this headers values:

```
request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
```

Current versions of dotnet also support `"br"` - `DecompressionMethods.Brotli`.
Using automatic decompression is helpful in nearly every case.

Comment: Yes! Thanks a million! 

- The handler property automaticdecompression

AND

- the polygon property of the content

were the key pieces which I was missing.